# Android Kiosk App: allow user to only modify Network Settings from (within) app

Tags: android, settings, kiosk

i'm working on a Kiosk App which requires Network Connection to load remote content.
The Problem is, that since it shall be a Kiosk App, the user is not allowed to access
Android itself and thus has no access to the Settings.

But, regarding Network-Settings, it would be great if a "privileged" User could modify
those only network-settings.
So, i could re-implement the whole Network-Settings Tab myself which would be problematic in
sense of android updates or having it correctly implemented, i think.

Anybody has suggestions?
Is it possible that i start the Network-Settings Intent and as soon as the setting is left my app goes into foreground again?
One, kinda weird, option i can think of, would be to periodically (every few ms) check which application is in foreground, if possible, and as soon as the net settings are closed i bring my app in foreground. But this would be kinda risky in sense of programming bugs or such.

One thing to note is, that i, under no circumstances, want to allow the user to access anything else on the system than my app and the networking settings.
Any ideas on this are highly welcome.

Comment: What's the issue with bringing up the Network Settings tab via intent? It wouldn't allow you to go anywhere else, as the back-button would take you back to your app, no? Have you tried it?

Comment: for example if i start the wifi intent `Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);` my fullscreen kiosk app goes to background and the main android title bar AND the wifi settings show up. Here i can use the main title bar to get to all other settings available which the user shall not be able to change. Additionally, i've enabled car mode (related to home key), as suggested for kiosk apps. which causes an icon shown in title bar. if the user disables car mode using this icon you get to the launcher and have full access.